# Alternate to any? which process complete array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a situation where I want to process whole array and perform `any?` operation on array to check whether some elements returns `false`

For example:
I want to print all truth values. And I also want to check anything is `false` in array:

```
def hel? 
  [true, false, true].any?{|x| p x; x}
end
```

The above example will print only first value (i.e) `true` and returns `true`. But I want it to print all elements of array and return `false`. Is there some other way to do it? or any change in same thing ? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? You said you want to print all truth values, and that you want to print all elements of the array. Do you mean that you want to print all the elements, regardless of their truthiness? And do you want to return false all the time, if at least one element is falsy, or if all elements are falsy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the values, do this:

```
[true, false, true].each(&method(:p))
```

To see if all of them are truthy, do this:

```
[true, false, true].all?
```

In order to do both, do this:

```
[true, false, true].each(&method(:p)).all?
```

Or, you can put it into one iteration:

```
[true, false, true].inject(true){|m, n| p(n) && m}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through the array you can use [`Enumerable#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_entry), but it won't return a boolean:

```
def hel?
  [true, false, true].each{|x| p x; x}
end
```

If you want to check all elements, you can use [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
def hel?
  [true, false, true].all?{|x| p x; x}
end
```

But in both cases you need to modify your block to get the same results.